# Xcode autolayout constraint landscape orientation issue where view shrinks to zero size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have a single view on screen that is constrained in the center x and y positions. It also has an aspect ratio to itself. The problem comes with the next constraints.

In portrait mode (compact width, regular height) it has a proportional width constraint to superview = 0.8 and this constraint is uninstalled in landscape mode.

In landscape mode, it has a proportional width constraint to superview = 0.4 and this constraint is uninstalled in portrait mode.

In the storyboard when in flip the device between portrait and landscape there's no problem and no auto layout issues, and the red view resizes according to the constraints, but in the simulated device and in my iPhone when I change it to landscape the view shrinks to zero size. I can't figure out why this is happening. Am I missing something? [image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different devices have different size classes.

For example, an `iPhone 13 Pro Max` uses:

```
wC hR   // portrait orientation
wR hC   // landscape orientation
```

whereas an `iPhone 8` uses:

```
wC hR   // portrait orientation
wC hC   // landscape orientation
```

Note that landscape is `wC hC`, not `wR hC`.

Change your "landscape" variation to `Width: Any Height: Compact`

[image]

See the Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/adaptivity-and-layout/) for a list of devices and size classes.

Comment: very nice, thank you